# Element selector for <code> tag is ignored in scss

Tags: css, sass

2020/02/23
 Added about my project. Sorry for lack of imfomation.

My project is fork of [Gatsby + Netlify CMS Starter][1].

I replaced `all.sass` with `all.scss`.

---

I am using `node-sass 4.11.0`.

I tried to compile `.scss` file like below.

```
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

code {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I expected css for `<body>` and `<code>` are output.

However, only `body` code block was output. Here is actual output.

```
body {
  background-color: #000000; }
```

Why the element selector for `<code>` tag is ignored?

Comment: can you provide the html code as well ?

Comment: Have you tried to compile other tags as well? Maybe you're having problems with your compiler

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved.

I'm sorry, but it was not because of sass compiler.

My project uses `Gatsby Plugin Purgecss`, and this plugin purges `<code>` block.

I didn't thought Purgecss judges `<code>` selector as unnecessary, because the html file parsed from markdown includes `<code>` tag.

However, as is written [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-purgecss/), Purgecss looks for selector only in `src` folder by default.

Answer (score -1):

Your code tags are inside of body?

it must be

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

code {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <code>
        teste
      </code>
  </body
```

Inside
https://codepen.io/novasdream/pen/Exjgqgg

outside have some bug has you see.
https://codepen.io/novasdream/pen/dyopxpV

Comment: OP wants to know why CSS rule for `code` is not being compiled